# Dictionary doesn't returns value from different class when it contains it

Tags: c#, dictionary

Im attempting to save information about users SteamID and his position in game, here is the code through which I teleport the person to the saved position each 0.5 seconds, and it works perfectly returning this information in console

**Key: 76561198333850828, Value: (605.0, 41.8, 618.5)**

```
  IDictionary<Steamworks.CSteamID, Vector3> numberNames = new Dictionary<Steamworks.CSteamID, Vector3>();

                        while (numberNames.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (KeyValuePair<Steamworks.CSteamID, Vector3> info in numberNames)
                            {
                                UnturnedPlayer steamidplayer = UnturnedPlayer.FromCSteamID(info.Key);
                                steamidplayer.Teleport(info.Value, 0);
                                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}, Value: {1}", info.Key, info.Value);
                                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5));
                            }
                        }
```

Yet when I attempt to remove the information from dictionary in a different class it says that dictionary does not contain anything

```
        internal void remname(Steamworks.CSteamID SteamID)
        {
            if (numberNames.ContainsKey(SteamID))
            {
                numberNames.Remove(SteamID);
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Doesnt contains");
            }
        }
```

And I have absolutely no idea what might have possibly caused this problem.

Comment: What is the relationship between the first class and the one that has the `remname()` method? Can you show us where you call `remname()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How have you defined numberNames?
If there are 2 definitions, one in each class, then they are completely different objects even though they share the same name.

Even if there is one definition in one class then, unless it is static  different instances of the same class will have different objects.

Comment: I defined it in the class of which you see first code block, I will edit so you see the dictionary definition, sorry about that.